# ifCond using handlebars js

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to make a logic if condition using handle bars using Or || but it is not working. how the || works in handlebars.

```
 <img src="{{#ifCond item.0.img_url '!==' '' || item.0.img_url '!==' null  }}
{{item.0.img_url}}{{else}}/assets/images/logo.svg{{/ifCond}}">
```

I am using this helper function

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {

    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!=':
            return (v1 != v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '!==':
            return (v1 !== v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

i have done it like that for now but i dunno if this is the right way to do it or not.

```
   {{#ifCond item.0.img_url '!==' ''}}
                {{item.0.img_url}}
                {{#ifCond item.0.img_url '!==' null}}
                {{item.0.img_url}}
                {{else}}
                /assets/images/logo.svg
                {{/ifCond}}
                {{else}}
                /assets/images/logo.svg
                {{/ifCond}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                {{#ifCond item.0.img_url '!==' ''}}
                {{item.0.img_url}}
                {{#ifCond item.0.img_url '!==' null}}
                {{item.0.img_url}}
                {{else}}
                /assets/images/logo.svg
                {{/ifCond}}
                {{else}}
                /assets/images/logo.svg
                {{/ifCond}}
```